# Sharing Servlet session with PHP

Tags: java, php, authentication, session, single-sign-on

I want to use a Java EE application server (GlassFish 3) as SSO service for both Java applications and PHP applications. If a user gets authenticated by GlassFish he should also be logged into the PHP applications.

Is there a best practise to share the Servlet session (more precise: authentication status) with PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [PHP / Java Integration](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.java.php). You can either integrate PHP into a servlet environment or have PHP call Java. Now I'm not 100% sure this will specifically solve your problem and the integration is deemed experimental.

What you're probably better off doing is using something else to share session data. Something like memcache. Both Java and PHP can freely talk to memcache. That will be a far more robust solution.

Comment: Or look at Caucho's Quercus for a Java implementation of PHP making integration much easier.

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with connecting PHP and a Java app server, but on integration in general:

A common way to do a single sign on is reading a session ID (e.g. a cookie set by the Java Server) in the PHP script, passing it to the app server internally (e.g. through the command line, by making a HTTP call or a shared cache instance) and getting back the authentication status.

If this is not possible, e.g. because the services are running on different domains, you would pass your app server's session ID to the PHP application the first time it gets called. The PHP app will then create a session of its own, and store the session ID from the app server in it. The internal verification of the app server's session would work as outlined above.

If you need to exchange more than just a "logged in / not logged in" flag, you could also look into replacing PHP's standard session handling using [**session_set_save_handler()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php). Your custom session function would, instead of storing the session data to a file, get its data from your app server, which can pre-fill session data with things like authentication status, user name, and so on. This would allow for some amount of easy inter-application communication as well.

Of course, first check whether the built-in Java/PHP integration functions mentioned by cletus don't already do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

i dont know about best practice... but usually if it works and is not ridiculously expensive and does not compromise security, it can be an acceptable practice.

when the user visits a php page without having a php session, that php page redirect to a specific jsp page.  the jsp page will see if the user has an active session.  if not the jsp page will allow the user to log in.  the jsp page will redirect to a specific php page, passing it things like authentication tokens and so on, as well as the url of the original page.  the php page creates the php session and redirects to the original page requested.  these pages could be in different domains and running on different servers.  this can also be replicated and implemented across different servers running java or php or anything else.

acc.intt/page.php  ->  sso.intt/cosession.jsp -> acc.intt/cosession.php -> acc.intt/page.php